# RestKit how to handle Authentication Failure

Tags: ios, authentication, error-handling, restkit

I'm unsingf RestKit in my iPad Project pulling some JSON Data from Server. The iOS app needs to authenticate via Basic HTTP Authentication.

If i enter wrong credentials, i can see on the console (Simulator):

```
W restkit.network:RKResponse.m:157 Failed authentication challenge after 1 failures
```

How can i catch this situation? I found nothing in RestKit documentation (and i'm sure there must be something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to implement the appropriate error handler in you `RKObjectLoaderDelegate`?

eg.

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error 
{
    RKLogError(@"Hit error: %@", error);
}
```

You should get an error with `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012` or similar.

Comment: I have didFailWirhError: implemented. I don't see any error stating `Error Domain = NSURLErrorDomain Code=1012`(or similar).

Comment: does your `didLoadObjects:` get called if you enter correct credentials? I just verified it in my app - the error handler gets called: 2011-11-14 14:39:20.126 App [53026:15803] W restkit.network:RKResponse.m:157 Failed authentication challenge after 1 failures
2011-11-14 14:39:20.142 App [53026:15803] E app:xxx.m:xxx Hit error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" Can you post how do you call ’loadObjectsAtResourcePath:’?

Comment: ah. i got it! now i see `The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012).

Comment: I send the log-output in `didFailWithError:` to a textView in the UI (i use kind of a log within the app). I was stairing on the console all the time to figure out why this won't work and forgot about the log within the UI of the App. Sorry for that!

Comment: The problem with that is that if your server sends some feedback on the type of error along with a status code > 299 you can't get the specific feedback, for those cases you can check my response bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Check the restkit response, I think you can check that using:

```
- (void) objectLoaderDidFinishLoading:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader{

    RKResponse *response = [objectLoader response];
    int statusCode = [response statusCode];

    if (![response isOK] || statusCode > 299) {

        id parsedResponse = [response parsedBody:NULL];
        if ([parsedResponse isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            //check for the specific error here!!
        }

    }

}
```